# Is there any stable Adobe Reader for OSX?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, adobe

I have version 11.0.06 which is very unstable.
Its average crash-time is about 5 minutes in 10.9.2 OSX. 
I cannot handle long documents at all.
Those which I type in LaTeX for instance.
Works well in Preview but not in Adobe Reader.
Adobe Reader goes very easily into overflow.

The same problem is happening in many new installations.
It is not in hardware, but in their software the problem.

**Is there any stable version of Adobe Reader for OSX?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the AR XI on my MBA 10.9.2.

> Architecture: i386
>
> Build: 11.0.06.70
>
> AGM: 4.28.134
>
> CoolType: 5.11.135
>
> JP2K: 2.0.0.32097

So far no crashes here with any kind of PDF, online or of line, in German and English with > 70 pages long ect..

Maybe you should look in your Console after a crash to see what is doing it.

Additionally some more information:

The Adobe Reader is not recommendable when editing LaTeX documents because it is uncomfortable regarding forward and inverse search between source code and PDF output. It does not support SyncTeX and therefore is only usable for viewing (and perhaps printing) the finalized document.

Comment: I am editing LaTeX documents all the time when Adobe Reader is open. Also, different tex-files, not related to the pdf-file in Adobe Reader. This apparently affects to crashes too. It is insane if I cannot have my TeXpad open at the same time as Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes, the last paragraph of the body answers the question. Problem with SyncTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I have Adobe Reader 11.0.06 and MacOS 10.9.2, but do not observe crashes.  Perhaps there is something else different about your situation.